# Add 1 to array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just would like to understand why this works:

```js
let newArray = [0,1,2,3].map(elem => elem + 1);
console.log(newArray);
```

and this doesn't:

```js
let newArray = [0,1,2,3].map(elem => elem++);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: the value of `elem++` is `elem`.

Comment: *"If used postfix, the increment operator increments and returns the value BEFORE incrementing"* [Increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is related to the `++` operator.

`return elem++` means return the original value of `elem`, and after that, `elem` value will be increased.

To fix this, use `++elem`.

Refer to [++ operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment).

```js
let newArray = [0,1,2,3].map(elem => ++elem);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want return elem after increase you should use ++ operation like this

```js
let newArray = [0,1,2,3].map(elem => ++elem);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are returning the values before increment. try this

```js
let newArray = [0,1,2,3].map(elem => ++elem);
console.log(newArray);
```